# Запуск фрагмента через пункт ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment

Есть фрагмент с листвью, мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на пункт листвью открывался другой фрагмент. При компиляции и запуске все идет без ошибок, но как только в листвью выбираю пункт прога крашится, ошибку узнать никак не могу, в логи не пишется... Что делать? Может есть другой способ?

```
package fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;



import com.gidanet.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TextFragment extends Fragment {
    public ArrayList<dost> dosts = new ArrayList<dost>();
    BoxAdapter boxAdapter;
    public TextFragment(){

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceSaved){
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_screen,container,false);

        final String[] name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name);
        final String[] text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text);
        final String[] audio = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.audio);

        boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(getActivity(),dosts);
        ListView lw = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lw.setAdapter(boxAdapter);

        for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
            dosts.add(new dost(name[i],R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        }

        lw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Fragment fragment = new InfoFragment();
                fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.layout.text_screen,fragment).commit();
            }
        });
        return  rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно добавлять новый фрагмент с помощью `FragmentManager` текущего фрагмента. Вновь созданный экземпляр фрагмента не имует к нему доступа пока он не добавлен в активити.

Итого замените этот код

> fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.layout.text_screen,fragment).commit();

на этот:

> getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.layout.text_screen,fragment).commit();

Comment: все та же история, крашится при нажатии на пункт...

Comment: Попробуйте заменить ваш InfoFragment на ваш же TextFragment при нажатии на список. Если падать перестанет, то проблема в InfoFragment. И таки реально ничего совсем в logCat?

Comment: Изменив Fragment fragment = new InfoFragment(); на InfoFragment fragment = new InfoFragment(); и поменяв контекст реплэйса на R.id.frame_for_drawer все заработало